# Contar while php mysql

Tags: php

tenho esse select mysql e quero contar quantos registros tem cada fornecedor, como poderia fazer?

```
$sql_visualizacoes_telefone = "SELECT * FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor=".$row['auxiliar']."";

$result_visualizacoes_telefone = $conn->query($sql_visualizacoes_telefone);

if ($result_visualizacoes_telefone->num_rows > 0) {

if ($row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]= $row['auxiliar']){

while($row_visualizacoes_telefone = $result_visualizacoes_telefone->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo $row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]." ";
}

}}
```

Comment: Dar um `count()` e agrupar pelo sql, não resolve?

Comment: Não ja tentei

while($row_visualizacoes_telefone = $result_visualizacoes_telefone->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo $row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]." ";
 $i[]=$row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"];
}

}}
print_r ($i)

Answer (score 1):

Para contar linhas no MySQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor = $auxiliar
```

Comment: retornou em branco

$sql_visualizacoes_telefone = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor = $auxiliar";

$result_visualizacoes_telefone = $conn->query($sql_visualizacoes_telefone);

if ($result_visualizacoes_telefone->num_rows > 0) {

if ($row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]= $row['auxiliar']){

while($row_visualizacoes_telefone = $result_visualizacoes_telefone->fetch_assoc()) {

 echo $row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]." ";
}

}}

Comment: claro, você só pegou a minha linha e jogou no seu código. A variável $auxiliar está vazia nesse caso.

Comment: ainda sim aparece em branco olha como estou fazendo

echo $row['auxiliar']." ";
$sql_visualizacoes_telefone = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor = ".$row["auxiliar"]."";

$result_visualizacoes_telefone = $conn->query($sql_visualizacoes_telefone);

if ($result_visualizacoes_telefone->num_rows > 0) {

while($row_visualizacoes_telefone = $result_visualizacoes_telefone->fetch_assoc()) {

if ($row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"]= $row['auxiliar']){
 $i_visu=$row_visualizacoes_telefone["auxiliar_fornecedor"];
}

}}
echo $i_visu;

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que contar e agrupar pelo nome do fornecedor já resolva o problema.

```
SELECT count(*) as total, auxiliar_fornecedor FROM visualizacoes_telefone GROUP BY auxiliar_fornecedor
```

Código php:

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) as total, auxiliar_fornecedor FROM visualizacoes_telefone GROUP BY auxiliar_fornecedor';
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die($conn->error);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["auxiliar_fornecedor"] .' | total: '. $row['total'];
}
```

Comment: retornou em branco olha como eu fiz 

$sql_total = 'SELECT count(*) as total, auxiliar_fornecedor FROM visualizacoes_telefone GROUP BY auxiliar_fornecedor';
$result_total = $conn->query($sql_total);

if ($result_total->num_rows > 0) {
while($row_total = $result_total->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $result_total["auxiliar_fornecedor"] .' | total: '. $row['total'];
}
}

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard testou essa consulta direto no banco, retornou algum registro? edite a segunda linha de código veja se aparece algum erro.

Comment: Não está conseguindo fazer a consulta com isso

SELECT count(*) as auxiliar_fornecedor FROM visualizacoes_telefone GROUP BY auxiliar_fornecedor

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard aparece algum erro no phpmyadmin ou no workbench?

Comment: a estrutua do bd eh essa

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `visualizacoes_telefone` (
`id` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `auxiliar_fornecedor` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `data` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard mas quando vc faz a consulta que eu sugerir (direto no banco) dá algum erro?

Comment: Desse jeito retorna certinho mais nao conta

$sql_total = "SELECT * FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor=".$row['auxiliar']."";

$result_total = $conn->query($sql_total);

if ($result_total->num_rows > 0) {

while($row_total = $result_total->fetch_assoc()) {
 echo $row_total["auxiliar_fornecedor"]." ";
}}

do seu jeito retorna em branco

Comment: tentei assim mais também retornou em branco

$sql_total = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor=".$row['auxiliar']."";

$result_total = $conn->query($sql_total);
$total = mysql_result($sql_total, 0, 'Total');
echo 'Total de registros: ' . $total;

Comment: @WagnerMartinsBodyboard sem código php vc consegue acessar o banco de dados?

Answer (score 0):

Pesquisando no forum achei esse código, mais ele só pega o primeiro registro, como faria para pegar os outros?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM visualizacoes_telefone WHERE auxiliar_fornecedor='".$row['auxiliar']."'", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
if($num_rows > 0){
echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
}else{
    echo "tabela sem registros\n";
};
```